# what is best source to learn Magento 2 including PDF,videos etc

Tags: magento2

I want to learn magento 2.Can anyone tell me what is best learning source including PDF,video,Online Tutorials.

Comment: If you do this, you will only be learning from Here at stack. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure of any videos on M2 but the best place to start with Magento 2 - is to start with the development documentation.

http://devdocs.magento.com/

And even then magento might seem a daunting task - if you have aren't familiar with magento already, i'd recommend looking into magento 1. Even though magento 2 is different, the database structure is the same and understanding the way magento uses **blocks** and xml to add these blocks is a great starting point.

You can also find more information on mage stores website, they seem to have a step by step on each section.

http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/

One of the best things you can do is get magento installed and play. Get stuck? ask a question or find a the question on here.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend this 12 hours course on Udemy. It teaches the core concept with real live project. https://www.udemy.com/simplified-magento-2-video-course-from-beginner-to-expert/ Disclaimer: I was part of the creator of the course.

After that, you can go for Magento study group. I found it quite useful https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer